# github DNS resolving not working

Tags: dns

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 and configured CNTLM for internal proxy authentication.
Unfortunately not all domains can be resolved.

- apt-get update / upgrade - works (configured apt.conf with the cntlm proxy info)
- git clone from internal network - works
- git clone from github : Could not resolve host: github.com
- wget [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) : Resolving failed: Name or service not known.

```
ls -la /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Sep 20 16:10 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
cat /etc/resolv.conf
    nameserver 127.0.0.53
    options edns0 trust-ad
    search xxx.xxx.xxx.com
```

I've tried several solutions but without success.
I would like to understand how is this possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to the git / wget configuration.
Both need to be informed abut using the cntlm proxy.

- git

  git config --global http.proxy http://127.0.0.1:3128

  git config --global https.proxy http://127.0.0.1:3128
- wget

  vi /etc/wgetrc

  use_proxy=yes

  http_proxy=127.0.0.1:3128

  https_proxy=127.0.0.1:3128